# Access Files Remotely on Windows using a Windows Service

Tags: java, windows, file

I have a Windows service that executes a `.bat` file. This `.bat` file executes some Sava code that reads some files' information. The files I need to access are not in the same machine that the service is running. So I should access them using a mapping like `G:\`.

Even if the files exist on `G:\` when I run the service, File `exists()` and File `canRead()` always return false.

If I execute the `.bat` manually, everything works great, but I need to execute it using a service.

The service is running with a user that has permissions to read all files on this `G:\` mapping.

Does anyone have a clue as to what can be wrong? Why can't I access these remote files, when running as a Windows service?

The OS in question is `Windows XP`.

Comment: try executing "\\servername\c$\path_to_bat_file", where c ist the drive on the remote machine and must, of course, be replaced with the name of the drive, on which the bat file resides (no mapping). This is assuming all access rights are in place, of course. servername is what you use to map the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem usually is that the user running the service does not have the same G: drive as well as the same access.

I suggest you log in as the user running the service and see what that user sees.

Comment: The user running the service is the same user that I log in when I execute the .bat manually. But if I run the service while logged in I get the same problem. Though, I can access the G: drive with explorer

Comment: Can you use the UNC path instead?

Comment: you do escape your backslaches, don't you?

Comment: yes, I do. Don't know what else to try... I also tried using file:// like in linux, but it didn't help :(

Comment: Worst case you can use an CIFS library like http://jcifs.samba.org/ which doesn't need drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

Drive mappings aren't shared between sessions, and service sessions don't get drive mappings reestablished automatically the way interactive sessions do.  You should put a net use command in the batch file to explicitly establish the drive mapping in the service session.